What is the Lagrangian density associated with the Gibbons-Hawking-York (GHY) term?
The Einstein-Hilbert action is
$$S_{\text{EH}} = \int_{\mathcal{M}}{\sqrt{-g}d^4x \left[\frac{1}{2\kappa}R + \frac{\Lambda}{\kappa} + \mathcal{L}_m\right]},$$
and the Gibbons-Hawking-York term is given by
$$S_{\text{GHY}} = \frac{1}{\kappa}\int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}{\sqrt{h}d^3yK\epsilon}.$$
Both are added such that the variation of the total action gives the Einstein field equations.
This is all fine for the action, but what would the Lagrangian density be? Note that the action of any field theory is defined as
$$S = \int_{\mathcal{M}}{\sqrt{-g}d^4x\mathcal{L}},$$
but the GHY term is integrated over the 3-dimensional volume element of the induced metric $h$. I would like to find the associated Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{\text{GHY}}$ density such that
$$S_{\text{GHY}} = \int_{\mathcal{M}}{\sqrt{-g}d^4x\mathcal{L}_{\text{GHY}}} = \frac{1}{\kappa}\int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}{\sqrt{h}d^3yK\epsilon}.$$

hint: use the generalized Stokes theorem.

Yes, the GHY term is a total derivative if you want to think of it part of the four-dimensional Lagrangian. Normally we ignore total derivatives in the Lagrangian because they become boundary terms by Stokes theorem and then we assume the boundary terms don't contribute to the action due to the asymptotic boundary conditions of the fields. But in quantum gravity calculations you shouldn't be so cavalier.

@Andrew Not just in Quantum Gravity, but also in General Relativity because otherwise the metric is overconstrained (without the GHY term, both $g$ and $\partial g$ should vanish on the boundary if I remember correctly).

@JeanbaptisteRoux Good point!

From Wikipedia,
$$\begin{align}\int_\mathcal{M} {A^\mu}_{; \mu} \sqrt{-g} d^4x & = \int_\mathcal{M} (\sqrt{-g} A^\mu)_{, \mu} d^4x \\
& = \oint_{\partial \mathcal{M}} A^\mu d \Sigma_\mu \\
& = \oint_{\partial \mathcal{M}} \epsilon A^\mu n_\mu \sqrt{|h|} d^3y, \end{align}~\tag{1}$$
and also from Wikipedia,
$$\frac{1}{\kappa} \int_{\partial \mathcal{M}} \mathrm{d}^3 y \, \epsilon \sqrt{|h|} K, \qquad K = {n^\mu}_{;\mu} = {n_\mu}^{;\mu},~\tag{2}$$
which by making use of (1) we may find
$$A^\mu n_\mu = \frac{1}{\kappa}K,~\tag{3}$$
so given $\epsilon = n^\mu n_\mu = \pm 1$, then a valid choice of $A^\mu$ in (3) is
$$A^\mu = \frac{1}{\epsilon\kappa}Kn^\mu,$$
which leads to
$$\mathcal{L}_{\text{GHY}} = \frac{1}{\epsilon\kappa}\nabla_\mu\left(Kn^\mu\right).$$
Edit:
In my previous answer I assumed $A^\mu = \nabla^\mu$ because $K = \nabla^\mu n_\mu$. Nonetheless, it must be true that ${A^\mu}_{;\mu}$ is an independent scalar and not an operator, so $A^\mu = \nabla^\mu$ is not a valid solution.
